# SQL Increment Column

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am trying to show one semesters aggregates in one column, the next semester's aggregates in the second column, and the third semesters aggregates in the third column. Also the real tables, I don't know how many status codes there are...

I have a semester table:

```
  Id    Semester
+----+----------+
| 1     Current |
| 2     Next    |
| 3     2 Ahead |
+----+----------+
```

I have a simple project table:

```
 Id    Title    Status   termId
+----+--------+---------+--------+
| 1      A        OK        1    |
| 2      B        Bad       1    |
| 3      C        OK        1    |
| 4      D        Bad       2    |
| 5      E        OK        2    |
| 6      F        Bad       3    |
| 7      G        OK        2    |
+----+--------+---------+--------+
```

This is the desired Output:

```
  Status    CurrentCount   NextCount   2AheadCount
+---------+--------------+-----------+-------------+
|  OK            2            1             0      |
|  Bad           1            1             1      |
+---------+--------------+-----------+-------------+
```

What would you recommend I do to be able to achieve this?

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. The first is a product owned by Oracle, the second is a Microsoft  product. They are not the same thing. Decide which one you're using, and then use the appropriate tag for it.

Comment: @KenWhite Yes that's true that they are not the same, however the syntax is very close, so it can be transferred very easily.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation with `group by`:

```
select status, 
    sum(case when termId = 1 then 1 else 0 end) CurrentCount,    
    sum(case when termId = 2 then 1 else 0 end) NextCount,
    sum(case when termId = 3 then 1 else 0 end) 2AheadCount
from project
group by status
```